# Nav with div inside (two different menus)

Tags: html, css, nav

I made an image of what I would like to do, sort of, but I cant seem to work it out.

What I would like:

[image]

I currently have the nav but it is all in a div, what I want to do, is to divide it, have two different divs and each with different content.

Here's my actual code.

**UPDATED:**

CSS

```
#nav
{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:7%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .5em 0 1em 0;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    right top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0, #E1A141),
    color-stop(0.43, #DF7266)
        );
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left bottom, #E1A141 0%, #DF7266 43%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left bottom, #E1A141 0%, #DF7266 43%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left bottom, #E1A141 0%, #DF7266 43%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left bottom, #E1A141 0%, #DF7266 43%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left bottom, #E1A141 0%, #DF7266 43%);
    }

    div#a
    {
    float: left !important;
    width: 50%;
    display:inline !important;
    }

    div#b
    {
    float: left !important;
    width: 50%;
    }

    #nav > ul
    {
        width:40%;
        line-height: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

        #nav > ul:before,
        #nav > ul:after
        {
            content: 'sentido';
            width: 300%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -2px;

            height: 5px;
            border-top: solid 1px rgba(192,192,192,0.35);
            border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(192,192,192,0.35);
        }

        #nav > ul:before
        {
            left: 100%;
            margin-left: 1px;
        }

        #nav > ul:after
        {
            right: 100%;
            margin-right: 1px;
        }

        #nav > ul > li
        {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: -9px 0.5em 0 0.5em;
            border-radius: 0.5em;
            padding: 0.85em;
            border: solid 1px transparent;
            -moz-transition: color 0.35s ease-in-out, border-color 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: color 0.35s ease-in-out, border-color 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: color 0.35s ease-in-out, border-color 0.35s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: color 0.35s ease-in-out, border-color 0.35s ease-in-out;
            transition: color 0.35s ease-in-out, border-color 0.35s ease-in-out;
        }

            #nav > ul > li.active
            {
                border-color: rgba(192,192,192,0.35);
            }

            #nav > ul > li > a,
            #nav > ul > li > span
            {
                display: block;
                color: inherit;
                text-decoration: none;
                border: 0;
                outline: 0;
            }

            #nav > ul > li > ul
            {
                display: none;
            }
```

html

```
                <nav id="nav" style="z-index: 9999;" id="navigation">
                    <div id="a">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#banner" class="scrolly">Encuentra</a></li>
                        <li><a href="right-sidebar.html">Aventura al Azar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#footer" class="scrolly">Contacto</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="b"> holibebe </div>
                </nav>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Enrique Bravo.

Comment: Um, use `div` tags if you want `div`s. ;)  If you want a `ul` in each `div`, then make your HTML that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your divs(1 and 2) to be 50% of their parent, in this case the `nav` element then float the divs and clear them.

BASIC example, going off of your image:

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mR3mq/)

Comment: It is working, but for some reason, the list goes crazy and stops being horizontal and starts being vertical. http://s14.postimg.org/lex003u81/Capture.gif like this. Is it being messed up by something else?

Comment: Updated, the list do show, but I get it vertically, even tho of the float: left

Comment: The issue now is that you are using the direct child selector `#nav > ul` however, your `ul` element is not the first child of the container. Try removing the '>' between `#nav` and `ul`...You should also remove the `height: 7%` rule on the `#nav`