# Can we have a div tag under nav tag directly

Tags: html, accessibility, w3c

I'm modifying a navigation menu, just thinking about best practices, can I have div tags under nav tag directly?

```
<nav>
     <ul>
        <li><a href=""> Home </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> About </a></li>
     </ul>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900602/nav-with-div-inside-two-different-menus

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov That is about stying, I'm asking about best practices.

Comment: Play with this and see if you can't answer your own question. https://jsfiddle.net/mR3mq/

Answer (score 2):

### Short Answer

Nothing wrong with adding `<div>`s to a `<nav>` element. As long as their content is accessible you will be fine. Obviously from a semantics / logical flow perspective anything within the `<nav>` element should be related to navigation.

Knowing your exact use case would be useful to offer exact advice, so the below is just general advice and best practices.

### Long Answer

From a [technical perspective the `<nav>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-nav-element.html) is just a sectional element, similar to a `<region>` and accepts [`flow content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/content-models.html#flow-content), which is pretty much everything other than sectional content.

### Best practices

From an accessibility perspective a `<nav>` element is **expected** to contain links and buttons (links for going to new pages, buttons for actions on the same page) and not much else except for supporting elements.

It is a good practice to add items in an unordered list just because it then announces how many items there are to a screen reader user, but the accessibility of the site won't suffer massively if it just contains links.

With that being said if you decide to add some `<div>`s to the `<nav>` element the worst case scenario is that screen reader users skip over them as they aren't expecting them to be there, they won't negatively affect accessibility (unless their content has accessibility issues of course!)

Finally make sure that the content of those `<div>`s is related to navigation in some way, otherwise they do not belong in the `<nav>`. If you are using them for some decorative element then ensure they have `role="presentation"` and `aria-hidden="true"`.

**For additional information here are some best practices with navigation:**

### Screen reader users will often navigate a page in different ways.

Knowing how screen reader users orientate and navigate through your site is the easiest way to know what you should implement.

#### By section

Some will iterate through sectional elements. For this reason it is probably advisable to have a hidden heading and label the section with that heading (the same as you would do with `<section>` elements).

This is less important if your site only has one `<nav>` element, but very important if you have multiple `<nav>` sections.

```css
.visually-hidden { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 - a 0 height clip, off to the bottom right of the visible 1px box */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); /*maybe deprecated but we need to support legacy browsers */
    clip-path: inset(50%); /*modern browsers, clip-path works inwards from each corner*/
    white-space: nowrap; /* added line to stop words getting smushed together (as they go onto seperate lines and some screen readers do not understand line feeds as a space */
}
```

```html
<nav aria-labelledby="mainMenuHeading">
<h2 id="mainMenuHeading" class="visually-hidden">Main Menu</h2>
     <ul>
        <li><a href=""> Home </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> About </a></li>
     </ul>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
</nav>
```

#### Navigating by links

Screen reader users will often iterate through all the links on a page to get a feel for what information there is on a page.

This is why we add the links to an `<ul>` and within a `<nav>` element so they know how many navigational items there are.

This is one case where having a `<div>` in your `<nav>` element might be a bad idea, a screen reader user may check the links in a `<nav>` element and then always skip the navigation (assuming you have skip navigation links - which you do I hope! hehe.)

If the information is important then sitting it outside the `<nav>` may be a good idea as there is a higher chance of it being discovered by screen reader users.

#### Navigation by headings

Some screen reader users (majority) use headings to navigate the page, `<h1>` to `<h6>`.

That is why we named the `<nav>` section using a heading earlier (in the "By section" heading), it benefits those users.

**This is not an exhaustive list of ways screen reader users navigate and it isn't just screen reader users we need to think about but hopefully it should give you some ideas of best practices.**

### Conclusion

That was a very long way to say, sure you can add nearly anything to a `<nav>` section. I just hope the above both illustrates that you can (and should) add additional items to a `<nav>` element for accessibility such as headings, but at the same time do not put any "mission critical" information within a `<nav>` element as it may not get discovered by screen reader users due to **expected behaviour**.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine as long as you pay attention to the accessibility.

The HTML Living Standard has an [example](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-nav-element) of a nav containing other elements (`p`,`a`,`h1`) and vaguely says that it "can hold other elements" so I don't think there's any specification issues here.

Additionally, Bootstrap does it in [their own Nav example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#nav) so I think we can also safely say that it's common practice.

I think the main consideration here is from an accessibility perspective. Screen readers will often [look for a list of links](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/structure/) within the nav section, so as long as you still have that `ul` element holding the links, I think it's relatively safe.